# Android: onInfoWindowClick never called

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, onclicklistener

I've implemented onInfoWindowClick through Android Google Maps v2.

```
public class myMap extends Activity implements GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        System.out.println("111");
        final String ssid = marker.getTitle();  

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_signin, null))
        .setTitle("Network Connection")            
        .setMessage("Connect to"+ssid)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Connect",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                wificonnector(ssid);
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        })
        .show();
    }
}
```

When I click infowindows of the marker (click marker first then click that label), it totally doesn't respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set this listener on the map `GoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(this)`

Comment: Can i just using `GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener` but no `GoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener`?

Comment: @atom2ueki no you can't. Where do you initialize your map? Just after that line put (whatever you called your map).setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

Comment: you're right, i need initialize my map with this on click listener then it works

Comment: @atom2ueki actually this should be `map.setInfoWindowAdapter(this);`

Comment: No, it should be `mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);`